# Process of joining in SQL

Tags: sql

The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all records from the right table (table2), and the matched records from the left table (table1). The result is NULL from the left side, when there is no match.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName
FROM Orders
RIGHT JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
ORDER BY Orders.OrderID;
```

For something like this, Orders is the left side table and Employees is the right side table.
Do we take a row from left side table, look at its employeeID and attempt to match with a row in right side table.
But if there is no matched value of the right side table, which row to return?

Comment: Then the row is ignored.  The result set is defined by the second table.

Answer (score 1):

In your scenario, the right-side EMPLOYEE record will be returned with NULL for the order ID.

Welcome, and as a newbie, there is plenty of reading and learning out on the web to many to list, but I will try to describe how I prefer to look at querying.

First, what do I ALWAYS want to have... In your scenario, I want all employees regardless of them having an order.  So I would start with the LEFT-SIDE table as the Employee.  Then, what else do I want associated with the employee... Orders in this case.  So put that as secondary (right-side).  The join is obvious on the employee ID.

so the left join is -- give me every record on the left (first table) regardless of there being a match on the right (second table).  It also helps to follow the tracking especially with multiple tables (3, 4, 5 or more using joins) to always think in this same principle.   All from this table where, but OPTIONALLY join (via left-join) to the secondary table.

Good luck with your learning SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no orders for an employee, it will return a row with that employee and NULL as the value for the OrderId. If there are one or more orders for an employee, it will return a separate row for each order that the employee is linked to (so there can be multiple rows of a single employee... one for each OrderId).

Answer (score 0):

Typically this will be implemented by working from the right table rather than the left. Every row in that table is going to appear at least once in the result set produced by the join.

So a *simple* way to implement this would be to iterate through the rows in the right table and, for each row, attempt to find rows in the left table that match it. If there are one or more matches, then we produce an output row for each match. Only if there are no matches from the left table do we produce a single row using `null`s for all columns that would have been supplied from the left table. This is essentially a `Loop Join`.

There are other strategies that may be available, depending on the database system and the join conditions. For instance, if the join conditions are all based on equality, then the database engine may first sort both inputs based on the columns in the join conditions. It then doesn't have to *search* for rows in the left table - just see if any are currently at the "front" of where it's iterating. This would be a `Merge Join`.

We shouldn't "start" with the left table when performing a `RIGHT JOIN` since it may contain rows which are *irrelevant* to the output result set. Only the rows in the left table that match at least one row in the right table are going to appear in the result set *at all*. It may contain other rows as well and these do not affect the result set<sup>1</sup>.

It should also be noted that there are other join strategies besides `Merge` and `Loop` - which ones are available depends on which RDBMS you're using, and not all join strategies may support outer joins.

---

<sup>1</sup>If we were going to use the rows from the left table as the starting point for a `RIGHT JOIN`, we would have to take each row from the left and attempt to find matching rows from the right. Each time we were successful, we would output one combined row. But we'd also have to track whether each row in the right table has been matched at all. After we'd exhausted all of the left rows, we'd then have to look through the right table again and output each row that hadn't been matched at all. I don't think anyone would attempt to implement this sort of strategy.